# What exactly constitutes a "flawless victory/defeat" in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm just curious as to what these messages "actually" mean.  In one case, we played a long hard battle of Dustbowl, and eventually the timer ran out.

Then, the Administrator said: "Flawless Defeat!  You didn't kill anyone!!".

I was extremely positive I had at least killed one person.  So why did this message show up?  What exactly triggers a flawless defeat/victory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm pretty sure something is wrong with the server setup.

Flawless defeat is when you lose without any of the opposing team dying **in arena mode.** Likewise flawless victory is when you win without taking a single casualty.

My guess is that the conditions for this is if everyone is alive on map end, and so on a non-arena map this happens regularly. The server must think you're playing arena and so is playing this sound.

Comment: I think there are other conditions for other modes, as I think that if your playing CTF and your team wins without the other team getting a capture, then it calls it a flawless victory

Comment: -1 - I lost on a control point really fast and got flawless defeat.